# Error while restarting laptop after installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, 17.04, restart

I installed Ubuntu and then it told me to restart, which I did. Upon restart it showed and error regarding failing to claim resource and other stuff and nothing happened, I tried pressing buttons and it typed but still nothing happened, so I turned it off by keeping the power button pressed.
I had to go through the installation again and then clicked on reinstall Ubuntu and it gave me another error: Two file systems are assigned the same mount point.
If I go on ok something new opens up, something loads and then it brings me back to the Installation type window.
I hope anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, during harddisk setup of the installation, you did something wrong. Such as defining two partitions for some place ('/', or '/home', I don't know). If your harddisks are completely empty, and you can wipe the data, then I suggest you only select maybe defaults during harddisk setup?

Actually, before doing anything, did you customize your harddisk during setup or did you choose a default option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just went with "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" if that's what you mean.

Comment: now that I think about it following a tutorial I went into something else as it advised me to create a switch area but then later decided to go since I didn't feel like trying around. May it be possible I did something wrong there?